# Python Pandas remove date from timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set like this

```
                         user  category
time                                   
2014-01-01 00:00:00  21155349         2                                 
2014-01-01 00:00:00  56347479         6                                      
2014-01-01 00:00:00  68429517        13
2014-01-01 00:00:00  39055685         4
2014-01-01 00:00:00    521325        13
```

I want to make it as

```
               user category
time                                   
00:00:00  21155349         2                                 
00:00:00  56347479         6                                                                     
00:00:00  68429517        13
00:00:00  39055685         4
00:00:00    521325        13
```

How you do this using pandas

Comment: do you want to change the values of or simply how it appears on screen?

Comment: I want to create a data frame by removing the date part from the original csv file

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mutate a series (column) in pandas, the pattern is to `apply` a function to it (that updates on element in the series at a time), and to then assign that series back into into the dataframe

```
import pandas
import StringIO

# load data 
data = '''date,user,category
2014-01-01 00:00:00,  21155349,         2                                 
2014-01-01 00:00:00,  56347479,         6                                      
2014-01-01 00:00:00,  68429517,        13
2014-01-01 00:00:00,  39055685,         4
2014-01-01 00:00:00,    521325,        13'''
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data))
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

# make the required change
without_date = df['date'].apply( lambda d : d.time() )
df['date'] = without_date

# display results
print df
```

If the problem is because the date is the index, you've got a few more hoops to jump through:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data), index_col='date')
ser = pandas.to_datetime(df.index).to_series()
df.set_index(ser.apply(lambda d : d.time() ))
```

As suggested by @DSM, If you have pandas later than 0.15.2, you can use use the `.dt` accessor on the series to do fast updates.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data), index_col='date')
ser = pandas.to_datetime(df.index).to_series()
df.set_index(ser.dt.time)
```

Comment: While this will work, `apply` is the method of last resort: it tends to be pretty slow.  In this case, we can reach for the vectorized `dt` accessor, and get the times via `df["date"].dt.time` (after we've ensured the column is datetimelike, anyway.)

Comment: It is also not necessary to convert to a series. The  `time` attribute is even directly available on the index (no use of ``.dt`` needed)